# How do I prevent Firefox from autoupdating?

Tags: automatic-update, firefox

Their new fangled update schedule is highly problematic.

I am using Ubuntu GNU/Linux.

Answer (score 6):

Under the "Tools" menu, choose "Options," activate the "Advanced" section, then select the "Update" tab; you'll be presented with a myriad of options for disabling or controlling how the updates behave as shown in the screen shot I've included from Firefox v3.6.23 below for your convenience (it looks the same in Firefox v7.0.1, so I'm assuming it isn't any different in Firefox v6.*anything*).

*What problems are you encountering with the update schedule, by the way?*

[image]

Comment: I am on Firefox 6 now on Ubuntu Linux. Under the Update tab, there is no checkbox for Firefox.

Comment: A problem I experienced yesterday is that Firefox 6 does not support Moonlight plugin (Silverlight for Linux).

Comment: I just tried to update Firefox, and it got me up to v3.6.23 (and couldn't detect any newer versions), so I went to the web site and discovered Firefox v7 is available so I installed that.  The configuration menus look exactly the same in both of these versions, and so I'm assuming it hasn't changed from v3.6.23 that I was using.  (Hmm, I installed Firefox 3 less than 6 months ago, and now they're already up to version 7?  Wow!)

Comment: Like I said, in version 6 on Ubuntu, there is no checkbox for Firefox under the Update tab. I will try to downgrade to Firefox 5, or switch to Chromium (I hope they don't update everyday too).

Comment: I wonder if the option got moved in version 6?  It's too bad that the option isn't there.

Answer (score 1):

Tools -> Options -> Advanced
Choose stop checking updates or check Ask me what I want to do

Answer (score 1):

You can set these prefs in `about:config` to  disable automatic updating:

app.update.auto - false

app.update.enabled - false

app.update.silent - false

Got these from https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1001740

Answer (score 0):

When installing Firefox, choose the customize radio button instead of default installation may be in 2nd or 3rd screen of the installation wizard and `uncheck`  Mozilla/Firefox `maintenance service`. It will certainly work.

plus:

```
app.update.auto - false
app.update.enabled - false
app.update.silent - false
```

in firefox configuration

plus:

Disable auto update from:
`Tools->Options->Advanced->Update->` select `never check for update`

Good luck